# How to get radius of trail with velocity and angular velocity?

Tags: time, velocity, rotational-kinematics, angular-velocity

If I know the velocity of something and the angular velocity of something, how could I figure out the distance between the object and the center it is rotating at?

[image: example problem]

I just need an equation for the range or diameter of the objects path with *X* and *Y* as used as above and, if possible, an example.

Answer (score 0):

According to your diagram the particle looks like is traveling in uniform circular motion. We can find the radius by using the relation

$v_{tangential}=\omega r$